# Translate pandas column with TextBlob

Tags: python, pandas, textblob

I'm trying to read a csv and translate one column that is written in French to English with the TextBlob package in Python (2.7.10 Mac OS X Yosemite).

However, Python throws the following error message at me:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

My Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from textblob import TextBlob

df = pd.read_csv('france_content.csv')
df2 = df[['HEADLINE', 'AUTHOR', 'CONTENT']]

TextBlob = df2['CONTENT'].str.strip()
TextBlob.translate(to="es")
```

On second thought, I actually think I don't need numpy here. But how can I make pandas to read the content field and have textblob translate this to English. Preferably placing this in a column named 'English'

EDIT:
Changed to:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from textblob import TextBlob

df = pd.read_csv('france_content.csv')

df['English'] = df['CONTENT'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').apply(lambda x:    TextBlob(x.strip()).translate(to='en'))
```

Data is very basic with in column 1 Author name and in column 2 ('CONTENT') the French text.

I still have the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: IIUC does `df['English'] = df['CONTENT'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob.translate(x.strip(), to='es'))` work?

Comment: No, that didn't work.

    TypeError: unbound method translate() must be called with TextBlob instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Comment: Hmm try this `df['English'] = df['CONTENT'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x.str.strip()).translate(to='es'))`

Comment: Ran that in IDLE but go the following error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: try `df['English'] = df['CONTENT'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x.strip()).translate(to='es'))`

Comment: Thanks. But now it throws another error at me: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: it looks like you need to decode to ascii first as I don't know whether TextBlob supports unicode or not

Comment: does `df['English'] = df['CONTENT'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x.strip()).translate(to='es'))` work? It would seriously help if you posted some data and more code

Comment: This code throws the same error:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from textblob import TextBlob

df = pd.read_csv('france_brand_ron.csv')

df['English'] = df['CONTENT'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x.strip()).translate(to='es'))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Please edit this into your question and post raw input data and code as this is becoming tedious

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from textblob import TextBlob
df = pd.read_csv('d:\lan.csv') # path to csv file
```

add english column in dataframe with converted words

```
df['english'] = df['structure'].str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').apply(lambda x:TextBlob(x.strip()).translate(to='en'))
df.to_csv("cool.csv")# your documents folder
```

This works as required.

thanks