# Extract Excel column and perform sentiment analysis using TextBlob

Tags: python

Below is my code.  I am try to extract a row (Row A) in an excel document (named Sentiment Analysis) into python and perform sentiment analysis using TextBlob and print those results.  I am getting the following error.  I can not seem to figure out why. I understand that the data set is in dataframe format and i need to get it to a string but i dont not know how.   Thank you!

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE6r1.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your code as text in the answer (so we can copy/paste and reproduce or solve). Also add the tag [tag:pandas] if you are asking for a specific framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to append a new column with the desired output to your data-frame:

```
df['sentiment']  = df['colname'].apply(lambda v: TextBlob(v).sentiment)
```

Note:

- Assumed the **column A** of your Excel sheet is called `colname` in your data-frame and contains the input.
- The function to *apply* is a **lambda** to create a `TextBlob` from value and derive the (attribute) `sentiment`.
- The output of apply is stored/assigned as **new column** to your data-frame, named `sentiment`.

See also:

- [Translate pandas column with TextBlob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691590/translate-pandas-column-with-textblob)
- [Pandas apply function to column then get attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57930254/pandas-apply-function-to-column-then-get-attribute)
- [Sentiment Analysis in Python - TextBlob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61509951/sentiment-analysis-in-python-textblob)
- [Using map() for columns in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529454/using-map-for-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)